# Kinetic energy of ball moving inside a circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, kinematics, rotational-kinematics

In a situation where a ball is rolling inside a circle as show here

[image]

knowing the linear speed of the ball, how would you go about calculating the total kinetic energy?

We know the ball is rolling around own center, so there is some rotational kinetic energy there.

But what about the kinetic energy of the ball's movement in the circle, is it translation kinetic energy or also rotation kinetic energy around the center of the circle?